# Get references without subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in table:

```
select p.number, pr.refNumber from part p, partref pr where pr.refNumber = p.id;



number                                   refNumber
---------------------------------------- ---------------------- 
1                                        1                    
2                                        2
2                                        3        
2                                        4
```

I need to remove old partrefs, only one partref should exist for part. 
At first I need to get all partrefs that should be deleted. Is that possible to do it without subquery (subselect)? How to do it?

---

UPDATE.

"OLD" partrefs are all partref records that aren't created at the latest.
So for example:

```
    refNumber                                  creationDate
---------------------------------------- ---------------------- 
1                                        01-01-13                   
2                                        01-02-13
3                                        02-02-13        
4                                        03-02-13
```

For part with id = 2, exists multiple partrefs like 2,3,4. Only 4th partref shouldn't be deleted since it's created at the latest.  Partrefs with refNumber 2 and 3 should be removed.

Comment: What represents OLD partrefs?  Which do you want to return?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible with either a join or a subquery, whichever you prefer, but you'd have to start by specifying how you decide which partrefs are candidates for deletion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your edits, this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.num, 
  MAX(pr.refNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Num ORDER BY CreationDate DESC)  as refNumberToKeep
FROM part p
  INNER JOIN partref pr ON pr.refNumber = p.id
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d66c4/5).

Good luck.

Comment: No, I don't. Selection shouldn't be determined by refNumber, but by pr.creationDate

Comment: @bontade -- btw, I used num instead of number just to be easier -- replace with your field name.  Good luck.

Comment: Hm, your query returns all partrefs, sorted by creationDate. It shouldn't return the newly created, if there's only one partref for part, no partref should be returned.

Comment: @bontade -- Did you click on the Fiddle?  it returns 1,1 and 2,4?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very good place for analytic functions.  Getting the ref numbers you want to keep is pretty easy.  However, it does still require a subquery:

```
select *
from (select p.number, pr.refNumber, pr.CreationDate,
            MAX(ref.CreationDate) over (p.Number) as MaxCreationDate
      from part p join
           partref pr
           on pr.refNumber = p.id
     ) ppr
where CreationDate <> MaxCreationDate
```

By the way, why the aversion to subqueries?  They are tremendously useful and a vital part of SQL.

Also, you should use proper ANSI join syntax.

Comment: I don't want to use subquery, because it's not efficient solution

Comment: @bontade . . . That is simply not true.  I think you need to learn more about databases and how they operate.  Subqueries are a very important part of SQL.  In any case, you could rewrite this query using `with`, which is just an alternative syntax for subqueries.